# Крестики-нолики на SFML. Проблемы с условиями

Tags: c++, sfml

Не думал, что когда-то буду сюда писать, но видимо придётся. Относительно недавно(год-полгода) начал изучать С++ и с ним же графическую библиотеку **SFML**. Делал функцию с условиями, которая возвращает номер клетки на поле 3х3:
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8

```
int CallReturn = -10;
int GetCellPressed()
{
    float PressX, PressY;
    PressX = Mouse::getPosition(win).x;
    PressY = Mouse::getPosition(win).y;
    if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
    {
        if(0.f < PressY < 190.f && Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
        {
            if(0 < PressX < 190) CallReturn = 0;
            if(210 < PressX < 390) CallReturn = 1;
            if(410 < PressX < 590) CallReturn = 2;
        }
        if(210 < PressY < 390 && Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
        {
            if(0 < PressX < 190) CallReturn = 3;
            if(210 < PressX < 390) CallReturn = 4;
            if(410 < PressX < 590) CallReturn = 5;
        }
        if(410 < PressY < 590 && Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
        {
            if(0 < PressX < 190) CallReturn = 6;
            if(210 < PressX < 390) CallReturn = 7;
            if(410 < PressX < 590) CallReturn = 8;
        }
    }
    std::cout << CallReturn << std::endl;
    return CallReturn;
}
```

Само поле же 600 на 600 пикселей. Возможно ответ на вопрос максимально простой, но что-то я посидел и ничего на ум не пришло.
[image: Вывод при нажатии на первую клетку]
При выводе CallReturn все время выходит 8, несмотря на то, что нажимал я на ячейку 1, что не так?

Comment: А для поля 10x10 будете выписывать двести условий?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не по сути вопроса - но зачем вы все время проверяете `&& Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)`? Одного раза на входе разве недостаточно? Второй вопрос - зачем `CallReturn` - глобальная переменная?

А по сути - `0.f < PressY < 190.f` - это **всегда** `true`. Потому что `<` - бинарный левоассоциативный оператор, так что это выражение - то же, что и

```
(0.f < PressY) < 190.f
```

Каким бы ни было `PressY`, результат `(0.f < PressY)` - `true` или `false`, т.е. 1 или 0 - что, конечно же, меньше `190.f`, и общий результат - `true`.

```
0.f < PressY && PressY < 190.f
```

Вот так правильнее...

Comment: Спасибо большое, как раз с этим были непонятки при изучении языка. Вот и аукнулось оно мне. Сейчас переделаю и скомпилирую.

Comment: Все работает правильно. Спасибо ещё раз, в следующий раз буду внимательнее.

Answer (score 1):

Разделите целочисленно `PressY` на 200. `Row = PressY/200`
Посчитайте также остаток от этого деления.

Если остаток меньше 10 или больше 190 - попали в мертвый промежуток, иначе запоминаем `Row`

То же самое для `PressX`, получаем `Column`

Номер ячейки, если оба значения не в мертвых промежутках

```
Cell = 3 * Row + Column
```

Получается примерно так (стоить заменить магические числа на константы или переменные, это поможет при модификации программы):

```
Row = PressY / 200;
Rem = PressY % 200;
if (Rem < 10 || Rem >=190) 
    return -1; 
Col = PressX / 200;
Rem = PressX % 200;
if (Rem < 10 || Rem >=190) 
    return -1; 
return 3 * Row + Column;
```